# BizTalk 2010 installation needed for build server (TFS2010)?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Is a (full) BizTalk 2010 installation needed to let a build server (TFS2010) build BizTalk 2010 solutions/projects ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my knowledge, BizTalk 2010 installation is not required. You only need below components.

1. Project Build Component available under Additional Software(to build the project)
2. Developer Tools and SDK (to run tests)

Comment: Thanks Jehan33, can this also be verified more by other experienced users ?

Answer (score 0):

I did find an apparent exception where if you deal with anything EDI related, it seems to require the full BizTalk install(not configuration).  I wanted to add this footnote for people experiencing compile errors where local compile works fine.