# MSBuild with BizTalk failing

Tags: msbuild, biztalk

I am trying to set up a build server for BizTalk 2010 projects. I have installed the "Project Build Component" portion of BTS 2010 Enterprise only. However, I am getting the following error when trying to compile the solution:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\BizTalk\BizTalkCommon.targets(115,9): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Maps\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Maps.btproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\BizTalk\BizTalkCommon.targets(115,9): error MSB4018: File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Maps\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Maps.btproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\BizTalk\BizTalkCommon.targets(115,9): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.BizTalkProject.Compiler.MapCompiler.Compile(BizTalkBuildSnapshot buildSnapshot, IEnumerable`1 mapFilesToCompile, IEnumerable`1 schemaFiles, List`1& generatedCodeFiles, List`1& xsltFiles) [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Maps\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Maps.btproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\BizTalk\BizTalkCommon.targets(115,9): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.BizTalkProject.BuildTasks.MapperCompiler.Execute() [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Maps\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Maps.btproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\BizTalk\BizTalkCommon.targets(115,9): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Maps\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Maps.btproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\BizTalk\BizTalkCommon.targets(115,9): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult) [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Maps\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Maps.btproj]

This error makes no sense. My understanding is that Visual Studio is no longer needed with the build components.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at repairing the installation.  You only need the build components and the SDK.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260881/biztalk-2010-installation-needed-for-build-server-tfs2010).

Answer (score 0):

I will add the following to the previous answer, as my reputation at this point is < 50 and unable to add comments:

- Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)
- Also please make sure your build command or build server is referencing MSBuild-32 bit (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe) instead of 64 (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe)